# UIDatePicker UIScrollViewer

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have UIDatePicker inside a UIScrollViewer. When i am scrolling date picker also scrolls. I want date picker to be fixed at the bottom. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the UIDatePicker to be fixed at the bottom of the screen, you simply shouldn't put it inside the UIScrollView.

i.e.: Just change the view to have a UIScrollView followed by a UIDatePicker.